# Interval within function gets called hundreds of times

Tags: javascript, canvas

When I call the function once, the interval is ok, it is added and cleared as supposed to. When the same function gets called again, the interval is called hundreds of times.
How can I stop this behavior and what is wrong with my function?

```
function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';

    // Add cube width 5px
    if(cube.width <= 300){
        cube.width += 5;
    }

    // Draw it on the screen
    ctx.fillRect(cube.x,cube.y,cube.width,cube.height);

    // Create function b(e) to check cubes collision
    function b(e){
        var x = e.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;

        if(x >= cube.x && x <= cube.x + cube.width
            && y >= cube.y && y <= cube.y + cube.height){
            ctx.canvas.removeEventListener('click',b,false);
            level1();
            return;
        }
    }

    ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', b, false);

    // Set the interval to 60 FPS
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        check += 1;

        console.log(check);

        if(check > 50){
            return;
        }
        // Call again the same function
        draw();
    },1000/60);
}
```

I suspect this is a javascript problem, so my guess is that canvas has nothing to do with this.

**Update**
The function I am calling draw from (which is inside another function):

```
    function a(e){
        var x = e.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;

        if(x >= player.x && x <= player.x + player.width
            && y >= player.y && y <= player.y + player.height){
            ctx.canvas.removeEventListener('click',a,false);
            draw();
        }
    }

    // Add the click event using the previous function
    ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', a, false);
```

Comment: you are creating an infinite loop, even you have not declared and initialized the check variable

Comment: This is just a piece of the whole software. It works perfectly, but you are right if you are just looking at this piece of code.

Comment: Since i can't see the check variable declaration inside the draw function, then it  must be outside the draw function and its look like you want to call draw function only for 50 time. So you can clear the timer when check become greater than 50, Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the problem. The problem is that at first the function works perfect, it reaches 50 and that is it. I want it to be called again and restart everything again. How can I do that?

Comment: What i understood is that you want to call the draw function once and the timer will call it for fifty time next time if you want call the draw function the timer should again call it for 50 times. am i correct?

Comment: This function of mine, animates the rectangle to a width of 300. After that, the animation stops. Also the user clicks on the rectangle, it makes it call another function which draws another rectangle. When I recall draw(), the rectangle stays 300 and I want it to reset the width of the rectangle, like the draw() function was called for the first time. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i understood, according to that i am posting this answer

```
function draw(check){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';

    // Add cube width 5px
    if(cube.width <= 300){
        cube.width += 5;
    }

    // Draw it on the screen
    ctx.fillRect(cube.x,cube.y,cube.width,cube.height);

    // Create function b(e) to check cubes collision
    function b(e){
        var x = e.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;

        if(x >= cube.x && x <= cube.x + cube.width
            && y >= cube.y && y <= cube.y + cube.height){
            ctx.canvas.removeEventListener('click',b,false);
            level1();
            return;
        }
    }

    ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', b, false);

    check+ = 1;
    if(check <=50)
    {
       // Set the interval to 60 FPS
       var timer = setTimeout(function()
       {
         // Call again the same function
         draw(check);
       },1000/60);
    }
}
```

Update The function I am calling draw from (which is inside another function):

```
function a(e){
    var x = e.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;

    if(x >= player.x && x <= player.x + player.width
        && y >= player.y && y <= player.y + player.height){
        ctx.canvas.removeEventListener('click',a,false);
        var check = 0;
        draw(check);
    }
}

// Add the click event using the previous function
ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', a, false);
```

You can declare the check variable somewhere outside and set it to 0 before calling the draw function from some other function or you can just pass the check variable with initial value what ever you want to the draw function

Comment: It doesn't work. I click on the rectangle and it doesn't animate unless I click on it. I want it to 'reanimate' when the same function is called. Basically, resetting the value of cube.width.

Comment: can you post from where you are calling the draw function

Comment: i edited my answer try this and check whether its working or not

Comment: In the other function from where you are calling draw just declare a variable call check=0; and pass that to the draw function

Comment: It says: Uncaught ReferenceError: setTimer is not defined. Wait a second I will try that. Tried that didn't work. draw(check), didn't work. I have already declared check to 0. The exact same problem happens.

Comment: Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nzap1yam/ I want this blue square to reset the value. Here is the fiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/nzap1yam/1/ Which practically is not the solution :/

Comment: That is exactly the idea! The only problem now is that I have to wait for it to animate totally. I want to bypass it so that even if you click on it while it is animating, it shows the green one.

Comment: Thanks! That is it! Can you please explain the solution to me in more detail? What I was doing wrong in the first example?

Comment: You was applying the eventListener on the element everytime you were calling the draw function. addEventListener does not overwrite the pervious handler so it was adding it to 50 time and all the handler was getting called while clicking on the element and since timer was based on the check value when we set the check value that time we had to clear the timer and apply the new timer

Answer (score 0):

You should call `setInterval()` only once and outside the draw function. The way you do it, you are starting an increasing number of timers that cause the `draw()` function to be called an infinitely growing number of times.
Alternatively: "To execute a function only once, after a specified number of milliseconds, use the `setTimeout()` method". Reference: [Window setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp). `setTimeout()` could be used inside your `draw()` function.

Comment: I don't want to call it outside of the function because I have other timers and this practically means I should put all timers outside of all functions.
If I put it outside, the draw function which was called by another function, makes it so that the timer never executes when the function is called, but it gets executed outside, running the same problem, infinitely.